# To get a list of people who are in online for a chat application using pubnub

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, pubnub

i had done a chat application using wpf and pubnub and i just want to implement it with xamarin and wpf .
In order to get a list of people who are in online for wpf i had just use  of presence method and here is the code snippet for that

```
    private void PresenceReceived(object sender, PresenceEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Event == "join")
        {
            Sample.HandleInvokeRequired(tb => tb.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem { Content = e.Uuid }));
            if (ApplicationContext.ListOfUsers != null && ApplicationContext.ListOfUsers.Count > 0)
            {
                var user = ApplicationContext.ListOfUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Equals(e.Uuid));
                if (user == null)
                {
                    ApplicationContext.ListOfUsers.Add(e.Uuid);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _hereNowUuids.Add(e.Uuid);
                ApplicationContext.ListOfUsers = _hereNowUuids;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (ApplicationContext.ListOfUsers != null && ApplicationContext.ListOfUsers.Count > 0)
            {
                ApplicationContext.ListOfUsers.Remove(ApplicationContext.ListOfUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Equals(e.Uuid)));

                Sample.HandleInvokeRequired(x => x.Items.Clear());
                foreach (var users in ApplicationContext.ListOfUsers)
                {
                    Sample.HandleInvokeRequired(tb => tb.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem { Content = users }));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In the same way i am trying to do it in the xamarin forms 
Instead of a listbox in wpf a listview is used and i am getting errors,and the code in xamarin forms is:

```
private void PresenceReceived(object sender, PresenceEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Event == "join")
        {
            LoginUserList.HandleInvokeRequired(x => x.ItemsSource.ToString().Add(new ListView(Content = e.Uuid)));
            if (ApplicationContext.ListOfUsers != null && ApplicationContext.ListOfUsers.Count > 0)
            {
                var user = ApplicationContext.ListOfUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Equals(e.Uuid));
                if (user == null)
                {
                    ApplicationContext.ListOfUsers.Add(e.Uuid);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _hereNowUuids.Add(e.Uuid);
                ApplicationContext.ListOfUsers = _hereNowUuids;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (ApplicationContext.ListOfUsers != null && ApplicationContext.ListOfUsers.Count > 0)
            {
                ApplicationContext.ListOfUsers.Remove(ApplicationContext.ListOfUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Equals(e.Uuid)));

                LoginUserList.HandleInvokeRequired(x => x.Items.Clear());
                foreach (var users in ApplicationContext.ListOfUsers)
                {
                    LoginUserList.HandleInvokeRequired(x => x.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem { Content = users }));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and my errors are:
1.Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Xamarin.Forms.View' SnovasysMobileChat  E:\Snovahub\SourceCode\Chat\SnovasysChat\SnovasysMobileChat\SnovasysMobileChat\Views\Chat\ChatList.xaml.cs  37  Active

2.Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'ListView' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) SnovasysMobileChat  E:\Snovahub\SourceCode\Chat\SnovasysChat\SnovasysMobileChat\SnovasysMobileChat\Views\Chat\ChatList.xaml.cs  58  Active

3.Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'ListView' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) SnovasysMobileChat  E:\Snovahub\SourceCode\Chat\SnovasysChat\SnovasysMobileChat\SnovasysMobileChat\Views\Chat\ChatList.xaml.cs  61  Active
4.Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ListBoxItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   SnovasysMobileChat  E:\Snovahub\SourceCode\Chat\SnovasysChat\SnovasysMobileChat\SnovasysMobileChat\Views\Chat\ChatList.xaml.cs  61  Active

Is it possible to do it with a listview in xamarin forms?

Comment: Not really an answer, but here is a chat app done with Xamarin.Forms maybe that's ll help you: https://github.com/EgorBo/CrossChat-Xamarin.Forms

Comment: thanks Nick, i just want to do it with pubnub only

Comment: WPF and Xamarin Forms are not the same, and you cannot simply re-use code from WPF and expect it to compile in Xamarin.

Comment: Jason, you are right and i had solved the issue with some modifications in the code